# Export a named export for each HTTP method. & Export a named export for each HTTP method instead

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, file-upload, next.js13

i am working on a nextjs api endpoint to upload image and text. i am getting this error in my local terminal

> ⨯ Detected default export in 'src/app/api/articles/route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method instead.

> ⨯ No HTTP methods exported in 'src/app/api/articles/route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method.

i am also getting this error in my devtools

> POST http://localhost:3000/api/articles 405 (Method Not Allowed)

this is my endpoint

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { createReadStream, createWriteStream } from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import formidable from 'formidable';
import Post, { IPost } from '@/app/(model)/post'; // Assuming this is your Mongoose model interface

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false, // Disable default bodyParser for custom file handling
  },
};

// Set the upload directory (consider making it configurable)
const uploadDir = './public/uploads';

// Function to sanitize filenames for potential security vulnerabilities
const sanitizeFilename = (filename: string): string => {
  // Use a library like `sanitize-filename` for robust sanitization
  return filename.replace(/[^\w.-]+/g, '');
};

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    console.log('im working')
    try {
      const form = new formidable.IncomingForm({
        uploadDir,
        keepExtensions: true,
        maxFileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, // Set a maximum file size (optional)
      });
      form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error parsing form data' });
        }

        const { title, category, tag, isHeader, isSlider, postContent, status } = fields;
        const postImage = files.postImage;

        if (!title || !category || !postContent || !postImage) {
          return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Please fill all required fields' });
        }
// Accessing the first uploaded file (assuming single file upload):
const uploadedFile = postImage[0];

       // Sanitizing the filename:
       const sanitizedFilename = sanitizeFilename(uploadedFile.originalFilename || uploadedFile.newFilename); // Use originalFilename or name if its available, uploadedFile.name gives error so i opted for newFilename(not sure if its correct)

       const readStream = createReadStream(uploadedFile.filepath); // Assuming `filepath` property exists
       const writeStream = createWriteStream(path.join(uploadDir, sanitizedFilename));

       readStream.pipe(writeStream);

        writeStream.on('finish', async () => {
          try {
            const newPost: IPost = await Post.create({
              title,
              category,
              tag,
              isHeader,
              isSlider,
              postImage: sanitizedFilename,
              postContent,
              status,
            });

            return res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: newPost });
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Database error:', error);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error saving post, please try again' });
          }
        });

        writeStream.on('error', (error) => {
          console.error('File upload error:', error);
          return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error uploading file, please try again' });
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Server error:', error);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Server error, please try again' });
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(405).json({ error: `Method '${req.method}' Not Allowed` });
  }
}
```

handlesubmit function

```
async function handleSubmit(e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();


    const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget); // Assuming a form element

    try {
     
      const res = await fetch("/api/articles", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type":
            formData instanceof FormData
              ? "multipart/form-data"
              : "application/json",
        },
      });

      if (!res.ok) {

        throw new Error("failed to create article."); 
      }


      const data = await res.json(); // Assuming the response contains JSON data
      console.log("Success:", data); // Log the response for debugging

    
      const router = useRouter();
      router.push("/"); // Redirect to the homepage
    } catch (error: any) {
  
      console.error("Error:", error.message || error); // Log the error message if available
     
    }
  }
```

Can someone help and possibly explain this to me so I can make sense of it for future reference.

Comment: are you using app router or pages router? The error is probably because you are using app router and after next.js v 13.0, the api routes are not defined in a single function and instead separate functions like GET, POST, PUT, DELETE have to be defined